# Error Connecting to ElasticSearch on CapRover

Tags: elasticsearch, caprover

Have installed ElasticSearch on CapRover using One-Click install; but got the following error when trying to connect:

```
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000019CF191C370>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Answer (score 0):

`CapRover` remaps the port of `ElasticSearch`: `9200` -> `80`

so need to either explicitly specify the port `80`:

`"<your url or ip>:80"`

or alternatively you can change CapRover's port mapping to `9200`